# golang - difference between os.stdout and multiwriter

Tags: go

I have this code to run `zsh` and log its output to an output file.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("zsh")
    f, _ := os.Create("log.txt")
    multiWriter := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f)
    cmd.Stdout = multiWriter
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Run()
}    
func haltOnError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

when the program executes, typing `ls` will output

```
foo
bar
```

while if I let `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout`, it displays correctly as

```
foo    bar
```

What leads to the differences between `os.Stdout` and `multiwriter`?

Comment: This is known, valid behaviour. The `ls` program uses the `isatty` C function to choose the default output format. When you use `io.MultiWriter`, `isatty`  returns 0, so the output format of `ls` is different.

Comment: @TimCooper is there any straightforward way to make a writer in go behave like a tty? I google a bit and find out pty but don't really know how it works.

Comment: @boh: why not do things the other way around and force `ls` to use the desired output format regardless of the output capabilities? Try `ls -x`, `ls -C` or `ls -1`

Comment: @wldsvc `ls` is an example of some arbitrary commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments by @Time and @wldsvc

The cause of the problem is that `isatty` is used by `ls` to choose the default output format, in this case the use of `io.MultiWriter` and `os.Stdout` result in different decisions based on the result of `isatty`.

The proposed solution was to force the output format of `ls` by use of the parameters ([man ls](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html)):

```
-C  list by columns
-x  list by lines instead of columns
-1  list one file per line
```

(documenting answer as show quiet high on unanswered list)